# How can i verify that input string contains numbers(0-9) and multiple .(special char) in TCL

Tags: tcl

I got three different entries "10576.53012.46344.35174" , "10" and "Doc-15" in foreach loop. Out of these 3 entries, i want 10576.53012.46344.35174. How can i verify that current string contains multiple . and numbers.

Im new to TCL, Need suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the sort of task that is a pretty good fit for regular expressions.

The string `10576.53012.46344.35174` is matched by a RE like this: `^\d{5}(?:\.\d{5}){3}$` though you might want something a little less strict (e.g., with more flexibility in the number of digits per group — `5` — or the number of groups following a `.` — `3`).

You test if a string matches a regular expression with the `regexp` command:

```
if {[regexp {^\d{5}(?:\.\d{5}){3}$} $theVarWithTheString]} {
    puts "the regular expression matched $theVarWithTheString"
}
```

An alternative approach is to `split` the string by `.` and check that each group is what you want:

```
set goodBits 0
set badString 0
foreach group [split $theVarWithTheString "."] {
    if {![string is integer -strict $group]} {
        set badString 1
        break
    }
    incr goodBits
}
if {!$badString && $goodBits == 4} {
    puts "the string was OK"
}
```

I greatly prefer the regular expression approach myself (with occasional help from `string is` as appropriate). Writing non-RE validators can be challenging and tends to require a lot of code.

Comment: Thanks Donal, its working with regex, "(?:\.\d{5}){3}$" in regex means 3 time . occurrence after a group of 5 digits ?

Comment: Yes. It means you want to find three lots of “a separator (`.`) followed by 5 digits”. There's another group of 5 digits before, of course. I'm using `(?:…)` as that's a non-capturing group, which makes the RE match faster.